# Unable to sent request to FCM url from server (same code is working from local pc)

Tags: java, firebase, push-notification, ssl-certificate, firebase-cloud-messaging

Unable to sent request to FCM url from server (same code is working from local pc)

***Below is the error i am receiving on server logs***

```
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Certificate for <fcm.googleapis.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names:  [*.googleapis.com, *.clients6.google.com, *.cloudendpointsapis.com, cloudendpointsapis.com, googleapis.com]at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.DefaultHostnameVerifier.matchDNSName(DefaultHostnameVerifier.java:157)
```

**Server notification sending code ( function )**
Same code works perfectly on local system/pc

```
public int sendNotification(String registrationId, String title,String subtitle, String url ,String destitle, String description) throws JSONException {

    String uri = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

    try {
                                            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(uri);
                                            postRequest.setHeader("Authorization","key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
                                            postRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                                            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                                            json.put("to",registrationId.trim());
                                            JSONObject data = new JSONObject();

                                            data.put("title", title);   // Notification title
                                            data.put("subtitle", subtitle); // Notification body
                                            data.put("destitle", destitle);
                                            data.put("url", url);
                                            data.put("description", description);


                                            json.put("data", data);

                                            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json.toString());
                                            postRequest.setEntity(entity);

        try {

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(postRequest);
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);


            //System.out.println("NOTIFICATION RESPONSE ----->"+msg1+msg2);
            String line = "";
            while((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(line);
            }


        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @grant ......yes below answer works perfectly......use the **gerHttpclient()** function below to create httpclient object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add host name verification code..... to create **httpclient** object

```
public HttpClient getHttpClient() {
    try {
                HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;

                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

                SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
                SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
                socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier((X509HostnameVerifier) hostnameVerifier);
                registry.register(new Scheme("https", socketFactory, 443));
                SingleClientConnManager mgr = new SingleClientConnManager(client.getParams(), registry);
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(mgr, client.getParams());

                // Set verifier
                HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);

                // Example send http request

        return httpClient;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

Comment: SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER defeats the purpose of SSL